# Camunda: correlate message where array variable contains

Tags: camunda, bpmn, bpmn.io

I have a process that with an array variable e.g. testVariable = ["a","b","c"] and its waiting for a message correlation.

Im looking for the way to creater message correlation to a instance where array variable contains specific value e.g. "a"

I tried this way, but still i cannot find an instance that matches the parameter:

```
      runtimeService.createMessageCorrelation(messageName)
                .processInstanceVariableEquals("testVariable", "a")
                .correlate();
```

I there any way to achieve that?